# Convert between UIImage and cv::Mat without copying the data?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv, uiimage

Is it possible to convert between an iOS `UIImage` and an OpenCV `cv::Mat` without copying the image?

The [examples in the OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html) show `CVGontextDrawImage` being used to copy the input image into the `cv::Mat`:

```
- (cv::Mat)cvMatFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image
{
  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage);
  CGFloat cols = image.size.width;
  CGFloat rows = image.size.height;

  cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC4); // 8 bits per component, 4 channels (color channels + alpha)

  CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data, ...);

  /***** image appears to be copied here *****/
  CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), image.CGImage);

  CGContextRelease(contextRef);

  return cvMat;
}
```

Comment: Did you find an answer eventually, sir?